# Autofill increment from another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using the formula `=MID(Sheet1!C3,FIND("Item",Sheet1!C3)+6,13)` and trying to autofill a large area but increment by 4. I use this one then `=MID(Sheet1!C7,FIND("Item",Sheet1!C7)+6,13)` and drag autofill but it won't increment the way I want it to. It ends up using C3, C7, C5, C9 instead of C3, C7, C11, C15. Any change in the formula I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some maths to create a stagger to the cells referenced when you fill down. A volatile formula like `OFFSET` may be easier to understand but a non-volatile function like `INDEX` will take up less calculation power overall. A volatile function is one that recalculates whenever the workbook goes through a calculation cycle, regardless of whether the value change would affect the formula or not. Examples of volatile functions include `OFFSET`, `INDIRECT`, `NOW`, etc.

**VOLATILE Solutions**

`=MID(OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$3, (ROW(1:1)-1)*4, 0),FIND("Item",OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$3, (ROW(1:1)-1)*4, 0))+6,13)`

`=MID(INDIRECT("Sheet1!C"&3+(ROW(1:1)-1)*4),FIND("Item",INDIRECT("Sheet1!C"&3+(ROW(1:1)-1)*4))+6,13)`

**NON-VOLATILE Solution**

`=MID(INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C, 3+(ROW(1:1)-1)*4), FIND("Item",INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C, 3+(ROW(1:1)-1)*4))+6,13)`

Pick any one of those (the last is recommended) and fill down as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OFFSET` function to increment by 4 cells each time, e.g. on its own that would be

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!C$3,(ROWS(D$2:D2)-1)*4,0)`

assumes first formula in D2 - change the ROWS(D$2:D2) part depending on first cell then you can use that twice in your existing formula to replace `Sheet1!C3`, so that becomes this formula

`=MID(OFFSET(Sheet1!C$3,(ROWS(D$2:D2)-1)*4,0),FIND("Item",OFFSET(Sheet1!C$3,(ROWS(D$2:D2)-1)*4,0))+6,13)`